# How can I scope CSS element selectors to component level in React?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Is there a way to scope all CSS selectors in a component to that component specifically? As far as I can tell various libraries that address the issue only work for class or ID selectors.

Our react front end uses some components owned by external teams that we fetch from a CDN. We use CSS modules to make class names unique but have issues with other teams using element selectors which are globally scoped and affect the rest of the page.

Comment: Styling by tags is considered a bad practice and this is another reason why. It's probably impossible to make a library that would make scoped tag styling.

Comment: I agree, this isn't good practice and ideally we would enforce some linting rule to prevent styling by tag but that isn't going to be popular.

I'm looking into possibly creating a wrapper class for these tenant components that would unset any bad styles but, like with other solutions, this does not seem ideal.